# Score Statsmodels Logit

Tags: python, statsmodels, predict

I can't seem to figure out the syntax to score a logistic regression model.

```
logit = sm.Logit(data[response],sm.add_constant(data[features]))
model = logit.fit()
preds = model.predict(data[features])
```

This is the traceback I am getting (sorry for the ugly format, didn't know how to fix it...)

---

```
  2     logit = sm.Logit(data[response],sm.add_constant(data[features]))
  3     model = logit.fit()
```

----> 4     preds = model.predict(data[features])

```
878             exog = dmatrix(self.model.data.orig_exog.design_info.builder,
879                     exog)
```

--> 880         return self.model.predict(self.params, exog, *args, **kwargs)
    881 
    882

```
376             exog = self.exog
377         if not linear:
```

--> 378             return self.cdf(np.dot(exog, params))
    379         else:
    380             return np.dot(exog, params)

ValueError: matrices are not aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including the constant in the estimation but not in the prediction.

The explanatory variable use for prediction needs the same number of variables, including a constant if it was used in the estimation:

`preds = model.predict(sm.add_constant(data[features]))`

It is often useful to add a constant column to the data frame so we have a consistent set of variables including the constant.

Related: The formula interface does some automatic transformations also in the call to predict, if they have been used in the model.

Comment: Thanks!  I chose this one because it had more explanation but these were both great answers.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you also need to add the constant to the predict method. Assuming you're working with pandas, it might be easier to do

```
data['constant'] = 1
```

And add it to your features list. Alternatively you can use the formula interface at `statsmodels.formula.api.logit`